# Override endpoint URL using @WebServiceRef on EJB via XML in JBoss AS7.x

Tags: jboss7.x, jbossws

In JBoss 5, I could do the following:

```
@Stateless
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService {
    @WebServiceRef(name = "services/MyWebService")
    MyWebPort myWebService;   
    ...
}
```

and override myWebService endpoint URL in jboss.xml:

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>MyServiceBean</ejb-name>
    <service-ref>
        <service-ref-name>services/MyWebService</service-ref-name>
        <service-impl-class>eg.MyWebService</service-impl-class>
        <port-component-ref>
            <service-endpoint-interface>eg.MyWebPort</service-endpoint-interface>
            <stub-property>
                <prop-name>javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address</prop-name>
                <prop-value>http://some.url.here</prop-value>
            </stub-property>
        </port-component-ref>
    </service-ref>
</session>
```

but in JBoss 7, jboss.xml is not used anymore and I can't find how to achieve the same with the new configuration file jboss-ejb3.xml.